# $.getJSON doesn't work, but accessing the query URL returns data

Tags: python, ajax, json

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import cgi
import os

print 'Content-Type: application/json'
print 
response={'host':cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"])}
jsondata=json.dumps(response)
print jsondata
```

I am unable request url throw the following javascript/jquery code:

```
jquery.getJSON("http://ourdomain/cgi-bin/serverscript.py", function(data){
    alert("----------");
 });
```

When I was browsing the same url, I am getting data.

Answer (score 0):

First, check that you're actually loading the jQuery library in your browser.  If entering `jQuery()` or `$()` in the console returns `undefined` or `[]`, then you're not loading the jQuery library in the page.

Second, the `print` method in your python code prints the data, but does not return it back to the calling function.

To fix this, change `print` to `return`.  Also, I'd suggest changing your function to the following:

```
response = {'host' : cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"])}
return json.dumps(response)
```

Your `print` statements don't do anything and the entire purpose of this code snippet is to get the address of the server environment.

In fact, this can all be done in one single line:

```
return json.dumps( { 'host' : cgi.escape( os.environ[ "REMOTE_ADDR" ] ) } )
```

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by using [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) request.